# Specific bullet list

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I'm looking to create a bullet list as follows:

```
(a) first item
(b) second item
(c) etc.
```

I've tried to google it and found the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]%for small alpha-characters within brackets.
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

However, this doesn't work for me.

I've also tried:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\alph{qcounter}]
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

but it doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \item etc.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \item etc.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Without any package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \item etc.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And virtual +1 for your removed answer to the question on aligning by amsmath tools.